# Python Multi Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to extract all the urls from an ip  list,
i wrote this python script, but i have issue extracting the same ip multiple times (more threads are created with the same ip).
Could anyone Improve on my solution using multithreading ?

Sorry for my english
Thanks all

```
import urllib2, os, re, sys, os, time, httplib, thread, argparse, random

try:
    ListaIP = open(sys.argv[1], "r").readlines()
except(IOError): 
    print "Error: Check your IP list path\n"
    sys.exit(1)



def getIP():
    if len(ListaIP) != 0:
        value = random.sample(ListaIP,  1)
        ListaIP.remove(value[0])
        return value
    else:
        print "\nListaIPs sa terminat\n"
        sys.exit(1)

def extractURL(ip):
    print ip + '\n'
    page = urllib2.urlopen('http://sameip.org/ip/' + ip)
    html = page.read()
    links = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', html)
    outfile = open('2.log', 'a')
    outfile.write("\n".join(links))
    outfile.close()

def start():
    while True:
        if len(ListaIP) != 0:
            test = getIP()
            IP = ''.join(test).replace('\n', '')
            extractURL(IP)
        else:
            break


for x in range(0, 10):
    thread.start_new_thread( start, () )

while 1:
    pass
```

Comment: It works ok to import `os` once; no need to import it twice.

Answer (score 5):

use a `threading.Lock`. The lock should be global, and create at the beginning when you create the IP list.

`lock.acquire` at the start of `getIP()`

and `release` it before you leave the method.

What you are seeing is, thread 1 executes `value=random.sample`, and then thread 2 also executes `value=random.sample` **before** thread 1 gets to the `remove`. So the item is still in the list at the time thread 2 gets there.
Therefore *both* threads have a chance of getting the same IP.

Comment: cooler method to use locks: [``with lock: statements``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement) (using [context managers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) )

Comment: def getIP():
 lock.acquire()
 if len(ListaIP) != 0:
  value = random.sample(ListaIP,  1)
  ListaIP.remove(value[0])
  return value
 else:
  print "\nListaIPs sa terminat\n"
  sys.exit(1)
 lock.release()
global name 'lock' is not defined
Not working ... I give me this error.